# High level vs low level motor control - acceleration and velocity profiles

Tags: motor, control-system, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I was wondering how are motor control loops normally run?

Lets say we have an autonomous car and a Model Predictive Controller defines a velocity and acceleration profile to get to the correct location.

Is this profile then fed into a lower level motor controller which actually adjusts PWM to the coils? Is this a lower level high-speed control loop a simple PID controller or something more advanced? How does it work?

I think the sampling requirements would be too high to have a MPC directly control the PWM of the motor controller and in addition it wouldn't be able to adjust quick enough to keep the more working approximately correctly.

Comment: MPC: Model Predictive Control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question depends a lot on the control architecture, and that is a design choice. But it should be safe to assume that you would have some "lower level" controller directly controlling the motor (due to simpler systems being more reliable and a PID controller being able to correct small model/system errors).

The MPC will probably generate the reference signal \$r_k\$ and some feed-forward control \$u_k\$ for the steps k, k+1, ..., k+n every iteration. That way it drives the system using the feed-forward and uses the reference (what state it wants to reach at every time-step) to let the PID do small corrections.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feAtkz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What is going to "adjusts PWM to the coils" it probably the motor driver, conceptually the controller generates a signal every time-step and the driver implements it using PWM or some drive signal, very different roles. But in reality, you might have a single micro-controller as your controller and also switching transistors (the motor driver role).

Comment: Ah ok, so you don't think the controller only provides a velocity or acceleration profile to the PID controller. You think it has a feed-forward controller in addition. In a real time system wouldn't generating this be too computationally demanding vs simply providing a profile for a secondary high-sample rate controller to follow?

Comment: For a real system, I think it is important to have some redundancy in case the MPC stops. Since the model for the PID itself is exact (you designed it) it wouldn't be hard to figure some \$ \tilde{r}(s) = r_(s)+PID(s)^{-1}u(s) \$ which incorporates the feedforward into the reference, but that might result in a very weird signal. The CPU usage would come from how frequently you run the MPC, and if you allow it to use only one of the calculated controls \$u_1\$ or if you allow it to run for some times steps using also  \$u_1,u_2,...,u_n\$.

Comment: I think you could run the PID at a higher frequency than the MPC, but I am not sure how that would affect the "optimality" of the control, specially if the PID ends up being the controller that does the reference tracking.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking the MPC would operate at a long time interval and the PID would update so quickly that it would always be able to treat the signal as essentially constant. Basically locally the system would always behave in an approximately linear fashion(IDK if this applies but you could apply some Lypanov theory where the PID controller is essentially using a linearized system model or something, I might be wrong).

Comment: MPC is not used to stabilize or change the dynamics of a plant, once you have your "lower level" controller stabilizing the plant you would apply the MPC output as a reference to it, but the reference and feedforward can be used together. If you are controlling a motor, having the MPC running slower than every 100 ms or so would be too slow already. And usually you solve the optimization but only the very first control \$ u_1\$ and in the next time-step you redo the optimization, but you could use more of those controls, say half of them, to reduce the number of time you run the MPC.

Comment: Hmm, I'm also kind of interested in how you stablize the plant, I understand basic MIMO feedback control systems and stability theory at equilibrium points but it's not clear at all how would really apply to an electric motor driving a car as the environment is so dynamic.

Comment: Maybe you could formulate a new question on that topic, also, first try reading some of the Astrom and Murray book Feedback Systems: An Introduction for Scientists and Engineers

Comment: I understand how basic feedback control systems work. The issue is the plant is always changing for given conditions but anyway thanks for the answer! Your combined approach makes sense I guess with the PID controller compensating for small variations.  Things like autonomous cars have highly nonlinear dynamics so a nonlinear MPC scheme is used(either direct shooting or iterative LQR or even grid search).

Answer (score 0):

PWM frequency has nothing to do with MPC update rate. Neither the velocity controller has the same sampling time of PWM cycle. You can choose a PWM cycle that suits physical parameters of the motor - e.g. inductance and/or max. frequency of the AC voltage output in case you use BLDC or PMSM.

The speed controller sample time is determined upon the examination of the inertia and amx. desired frequency response of this control loop. If this is a vehicle, then some tens of msec is just enough.

The MPC can be even slower update.

Comment: Ok, so how exactly does it work per my OP?